# Turning a screen into a virtual web cam

Tags: macos, webcam, quicktime

Is there an app (preferable a Mac app) that will turn an area of your screen into a virtual web cam, such that it would be available as an input source for other apps that want to access your web cam?

Comment: In 2022, is there a working app for this use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CamTwist** *(Mac)*

Allows you to turn your desktop into a cam image. *And it is free.*

[Download it here](http://camtwist.en.softonic.com/mac/download)

*If you're on Windows take a look at **ManyCam***

Comment: CamTwist is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Nick.

Comment: It even lets you broadcast a specific window. Perfect.

Comment: Thanks, I have a Mac Pro without a web cam, but the application I’m programming has AV capture functionality. This app is the perfect fit if you want to simulate a real camera! You can even pass-through your default audio input device. You can even add effects to make sure that “something happens” at all.

Answer (score 0):

or how about:

**webcamstudio** *(Linux)*

it's java so there should be ports to most systems?

http://www.ws4gl.org/

http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/

-or-

**CamCamX** *(Mac)*

a bit more on the shady side ($99!) but i've installed it and it seems like it could be  snazzy, post-licensing... however it's not as great as CamTwist...

http://b-l-a-c-k-o-p.com/CamCamX.html